# Двумерный массив, указатели и вывод значений элементов массива в c++

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, указатели, c++14

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вот в этом коде

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int arr[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {
        cout << arr[i] << '\t' << sizeof(arr[i]) << '\n';
    }
}
```

выводятся следующие значения:

```
0x61fdf0        12
0x61fdfc        12
0x61fe08        12
0x61fe14        12
0x61fe20        12
0x61fe2c        12
0x61fe38        12
0x61fe44        12
0x61fe50        12
```

То есть почему размер адресов переменных двумерного массива равен 12 байтам, при этом разница между соседними адресами, например, `0x61fe14` и `0x61fe20` составляет 6 байтов? Откуда вообще взялись эти числа, если целые числа занимают 4 байта.

P.S. И почему вообще, если вывести `arr[i]` выведется именно адрес переменной? То есть, в случае одномерного массива, если есть переменная `arr[i]`, то ее адрес - `&arr[i]`. Почему нельзя было адрес переменной выводить только как `&arr[i][j]`, зачем вторая интерпретация? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы выводите строки (по 3 элемента в строке), cout выводит адреса (а что тут еще можно выводить?) первого элемента строки / А 0xe20 - 0xe14 = 0xc (12 decimal) -- это размер строки из 3-х элементов

Comment: @avp но ведь разница между 0x61fe20 и 0x61fe14 - 6 байт, а не 12.

Comment: `0x20 - 0x14 == 0xC == 12` Не верите? [Пример](https://ideone.com/vByat0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запись

```
int arr[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

эквивалентна записи

```
int arr[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Следовательно, `arr` есть одномерный массив из трёх элементов. А элементы массива `arr` сами являются одномерными массивами из трёх элементов типа `int`.

Таким образом, имеем следующий расклад:
тип `arr` — это `int[3][3]`,
тип `arr[i]` — это `int[3]`,
тип `arr[i][j]` — это `int`.

```
sizeof(arr) == 3 * sizeof(int[3]) == 3 * (3 * sizeof(int)) // == 3 * (3 * 4), если sizeof(int) == 4
```

---

> То есть почему размер адресов переменных двумерного массива равен 12 байтам

Потому что `arr[i]` — это не адрес переменной двумерного массива, а одномерный массив из трёх элементов типа `int`. Оператор `sizeof` применённый к массиву, возвращает количество байтов, занимаемых массивом.

> И почему вообще, если вывести arr[i] выведется именно адрес переменной?

Потому что нет перегруженного оператора `<<` для вывода массива интов, но есть оператор для вывода указателей `const void*`. А массив может быть неявно преобразован в указатель на свой первый элемент, а указатель `int*` может быть неявно преобразован в `const void*`.

Обратите внимание, что если массив `arr[i]` преобразуется в указатель, то это указатель на инт: `int*`. В то время как адрес самого массива `&arr[i]` имеет тип указателя на массив из трёх элементов типа инт: `int(*)[3]`.

> при этом разница между соседними адресами, например, `0x61fe14` и `0x61fe20` составляет 6 байтов?

Использование букв в качестве цифр в записи числа вас не смутило? ;) Префикс `0x` сигнализирует о том, что числа записаны в [шестнадцатеричной системе счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Более наглядно разницу вы увидите, посчитав разность между вторым и первым адресами:

```
0x61fdfc - 0x61fdf0 == 0xC == 12 (в десятичной) == sizeof(int[3]) == 3 * sizeof(int)
```

Наконец, так как в массиве `arr` всего три элемента, то и цикл должен быть от нуля до трёх:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Если хотите вывести самые вложенные `int`'ы используете два цикла:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: А я правильно понимаю, что, если массив arr[i] преобразуется в указатель, то это указатель на инт: int*, потому что он указывает именно на первый элемент i-й строки. Но я не понимаю почему адрес самого массива строк &arr[i] имеет тип указателя на массив из трёх элементов типа инт: int(*)[3]. Адрес же можно брать только у отдельного элемента, соответственно и указатель должен быть на отдельный элемент. Адрес чего вообще берется, когда мы пишем &arr[i]? Массив адресов массива строк или что?

Comment: @prostak, возможно вам будет проще понять на примере структуры: `struct my_struct {int a; int b;} s;` Можно взять адрес поля `a` структуры `s`: `int* pa = &s.a`, можно взять адрес самой структуры `s`: `my_struct* ps = &s;`. Оба указателя `pa` и `ps` будут хранить один и тот же адрес, но `pa` указывает всего лишь на маленький `int`, в то время как `ps` указывает на всю структуру. Аналогично и с массивами. Указатель может указывать не только на элемент массива, но и на весь массив. Посмотрите [пример кода](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da2b2c79a265e83e).

Comment: @prostak, адреса одинаковые, разные типы указателей) Отсюда разная арифметика +1, например.