# Что же на самом деле такое имя двумерного массива?

Tags: c++, c

Если создать автоматический двумерный массив, например:

```
int Array[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```

Этот массив будет расположен на стеке последовательно, как-бы одномерный. Если это так, тогда `Array` == адресу его начала и `*Array` - имеет тот же адрес. То есть `Array == *Array`, то есть `Array` хранит адрес самого себя, но если вывести

`std::cout << &array[0][0] << " " << array << " " << *array;`

Будут одинаковые адреса во 3-х случаях, припустим `0x0000AD34`. С этого следует, что по адресу `0x0000AD34` лежит эллемент `[0][0]` и одновременно этот адрес.

То что же такое `Array`? Перед тем, как отвечать попробуйте поиграться с подобными примерами.

Comment: На хабре была хорошая статья на эту тему.

Comment: Вот она: https://habr.com/ru/post/251091/

Comment: Просто взять std::vector или std::array и всё, а то с этими двумерными массивами проблем можно много хапнуть.

Comment: Это одномерный массив элементов типа `int[3]`. Все просто :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Имя массива — это указатель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005812/%d0%98%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: [Двумерный массив, указатели и вывод значений элементов массива в c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230113)

Answer (score 3):

Двумерный массив элементов в памяти реализован как одномерный массив одномерных массивов. Например : `int Array[2][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };` будет реализован так :

```
0x8000 : Array : Array[0] : Array[0][0] : 1
0x8004 :                  : Array[0][1] : 2
0x8008 :                  : Array[0][2] : 3
0x800c :       : Array[1] : Array[1][0] : 4
0x8010 :                  : Array[1][1] : 5
0x8014 :                  : Array[1][2] : 6
```

Адрес массива `&Array` равен `0x8000` а ряд массива `Array[0]` и элемент массива `Array[0][0]` имеет один и тот-же адрес `0x8000`.